# AngularJS: Call function after user makes selection in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, switch-statement, readfile

so I have a dropdown and added some values as shown below.
I want the program to do stuff based on the selected options from drop box.

```
angular.module('priceCalculator', [])
.controller("mainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.data = {
  availableOptions: [
    {id: 0, name: 'Please Select'},
    {id: 1, name: 'PVC Red Extra'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Alu Standard'},
    {id: 3, name: 'SKS Classic Decor'},
    {id: 4, name: 'SKS Aluminiu Alb'}
  ],

  selectedOption: {id: 0, name: 'Please Select'}
};
}]);
```

I was thinking I could do it with a switch statement

```
$scope.doStuff = function() {
  switch(id from availableOptions) {
    case 0: 
    // do stuff, I want to read file based on inputs I shall also get from user
    break;
    default:
    // do stuff
  };
};
```

How do I need to do this? Sorry if it's easy for everybody, I'm really noob at coding

Here's the html section

```
  <label>Select Shutter Type</label>
  <!-- Use ngOption to select shutter type -->
  <select ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" ng-model="data.selectedOption">
  </select>
```

Comment: Yes you can do that, what is the issue now?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you would like your `doStuff` function to be called when the selection changes. You can use `ng-change` to do that:

```
<select 
  ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" 
  ng-model="data.selectedOption"
  ng-change="doStuff(option)">
```

Then you can declare `doStuff` like this:

```
$scope.doStuff = function(selectedOption) {
```